# Giveaway not started even after using start command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently doing a bot project, and having a giveaway feature, so basically I do p!start

the bot only send "Giveaway started in (channel name)"

but not showing the message regarding the giveaway

Here's my code, any solution for this, appreciate for your time

```
run: async (bot, message, args) => {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES') && !message.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.name === "Giveaways")){
     return message.channel.send(':x: You need to have the manage messages permissions to start giveaways.');
 }
 let giveawayChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
 if(!giveawayChannel){
     return message.channel.send(':x: You have to mention a valid channel!');
 }

 let giveawayDuration = args[1];
 if(!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))){
     return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid duration!');
 }

 let giveawayNumberWinners = args[2];
 if(isNaN(giveawayNumberWinners) || (parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners) <= 0)){
     return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid number of winners!');
 }

 let giveawayPrize = args.slice(3).join(' ');
 if(!giveawayPrize){
     return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid prize!');
 }

 bot.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
     
     time: ms(giveawayDuration),
     prize: giveawayPrize,
     winnerCount: giveawayNumberWinners,
     hostedBy: message.author,
     message: {
         giveaway: " **GIVEAWAY** ",
         giveawayEnded: " **GIVEAWAY ENDED** ",
         timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
         inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
         winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won **{prize}**!",
         embedFooter: "Giveaways",
         noWinner: "Giveaway cancelled, no valid participations.",
         hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
         winners: "winner(s)",
         endedAt: "Ended at",
         units: {
             seconds: "seconds",
             minutes: "minutes",
             hours: "hours",
             days: "days",
             pluralS: false     
         }
     }
 });

}
 message.channel.send(`Giveaway started in ${giveawayChannel}!`);

 }
}
```

Comment: What is that file and why do you have the run method twice?

Comment: accidentally copy paste the code twice and somehow the run command into above the bot.giveaway, should be edited

Comment: You have 9 opening brackets and 11 closing ones. How come? Is the giveaway started message outside the run command? If yes, in what scope it is? Quite unclear what I'm looking at

Comment: the 2 extra bracket is from module export that I don't include